# Bootstrap-Datepicker not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, datepicker

I'm trying to use a bootstrap-datepicker for my RoR application, specifically [this one](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker).

I've downloaded the js file and put it in the assets/javascripts folder

then I made a single view in order to make it work in the simplest way possible, this is what it has

```
<input type="text" value="02-16-2012" class="datepicker">

<script>
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
     format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
 });
</script>
```

It naturally shows the textfield with "02-16-2012" in it, but it doesn't make the little calendar to pop up at click. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Here's what my application.js file has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
```

And what my application.css flie has:

```
*= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require bootstrap
```

The console displays 2 errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/default.css
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'              test:113
```

Also the output for `console.log($('.datepicker'))` is:

```
[input.datepicker, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: ".datepicker", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selector is missing a dot (`.`), you need to add a dot to capture all the elements having `datepicker` as class:

```
<input type="text" value="02-16-2012" class="datepicker">

<script>
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
     format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
 });
</script>
```

You may want to "secure" your datepicker deployment on only inputs having `datepicker` class:

```
$('input.datepicker').datepicker({ # match every input having 'datepicker' class
  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
});
```

Maybe try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
})
```

Comment: What does your console says? (F12 on Google Chrome, 'Console' tab) Is there any errors on the page you are trying to add the Datepicker?

Comment: yes, the console has 2 errors

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'`

Comment: can you tell me the output of `console.log($('.datepicker'))` please?

Comment: here `[input.datepicker, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: ".datepicker", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]`

Comment: The Datepicker javascript library is not included well in your page, if I do `$().datepicker();` in my project it returns me an empty array, not a TypeError

Comment: You need to include the following libraries: `jquery.js`, `bootstrap.js` & `bootstrap-datepicker.js`

Comment: Sorry for answering this late. I have installed the gems `'twitter-bootstrap-rails'`, `'jquery-rails'` and `'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'` so des it mean that the libraries are included?

Comment: Nope, you need to explicitly add them in your layout https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails

Comment: put `<script type="text/javascript" src="/asset/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="/asset/javascripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>` you mean?... because It didn´t work either

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the datepicker css.

Comment: thanks, I added the .css but nothing happened, still not working. though It should work without that, right?

Answer (score 0):

The required markup from the documentation (specifically, you need to add the span.add-on and i.icon-th):

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" 
  data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The first example says something different: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker#example

Answer (score 0):

To get the CSS and Javascript properly packed in rails assets pipeline, I recommend you to use this gem: https://github.com/lubieniebieski/bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails